# Can you get back miles you didn't fly because you were rebooked on another Airline/Alliance?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs, american-airlines

I was recently due to fly on American Airlines, but my flights were cancelled at the last minute. They rebooked me on US Airways (not the same alliance), via a slightly different route, and I didn't get any miles in my AAdvantage account as a consequence, despite not getting any monetary refund on the flights.

Does anyone have any experience trying to get miles added retrospectively in circumstances such as this? How did you do it? If you've managed to get them added, were they elite-qualifying?

I'm AAdvantage Executive Platinum, if it makes a difference.

Please note: I don't think this is documented anywhere in the rules (although I could stand corrected!) so I'm looking more for specific experience.

Comment: This is exactly what was needed. I recently flew AA on MIA LAX NRT SIN, the flight out of LAX to NRT arrived late and as a result the Narita ground staff met me and 3 others booked on the same JAL flight to Singapore with Singapore Airlines tickets a couple hours later. My trip was basically a mileage run to re qualify EXPLAT , so I called AA, about credit, at first I was getting nowhere until I mentioned the magic words "original routing credit" and "involuntary rerouting". I got a call back within an hour informing me that the miles were in my account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contact AAdvantage and request *original routing credit* due to your *involuntary rerouting*. Provide scans of your new boarding passes, your PNR and ticket number, and a short description of what happened.

It is very likely AA will credit you for RDMs and EQMs as a goodwill gesture for the cancellation, although you may not receive segment, e500, or specal promotion credit for the flight.

This is one of the extremely rare cases where it is possible to double-dip. You can request your new flights to be credited to US Airways (or another Star Alliance carrier, such as United), and receive those in addition to the AAdvantage miles. Of course, since AA and US Airways are merging, if you can keep the US Airways account alive for another year and a half or so, you can merge miles from both accounts into the new program as well.

Comment: OK, thanks, and thanks for the help with the terminology. Sounds like what I needed. Will contact them and see what happens...

Comment: For what it's worth, I just filled out the online reclaim form on aa.com for missing miles. They popped up in my account a few weeks later (for the US Airways route, not the original AA one). I can't say if it was down to being Exec Platinum, though..